# Python selenium/Beautifulsoup using urlretrieve 403 forbidden error

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

Please understand that I am not good at English.

I created a crawl program that downloads images using image URLs

Get the image URL in the imgs_urls array.

Then downloads them using the urlretrieve function using those URLs.

I get an 403 forbidden error before using all the urls in the array.

#####syncopation###### was used because of the limit of 30000 characters

How can I fix the error?

## code:

```
def Remainder_All_ImagesURLs_Google(searchText):
 def scroll_page():
     for i in range(7): 
         driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
         sleep(3) 

 def click_button():
     more_imgs_button_xpath = "//*[@id='smb']" 
     element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(more_imgs_button_xpath)
     element.click()
     sleep(3)

 def create_soup():
     html_source = driver.page_source
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
     return soup

 driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/ajh46\Anaconda3/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe')
 driver.maximize_window()
 sleep(2)

 searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q={}&site=webhp&tbm=isch".format(searchText)

 driver.get(searchUrl)

 try:
     scroll_page()
     click_button()
     scroll_page()

 except:
     click_button()
     scroll_page() 


 imgs_urls = [] 
 cnt = 0

 for j in range(100):
     element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-ri = '" + str(cnt + j) + "'] img")
     element.click()
     sleep(1)

     soup = create_soup() 

     for img in soup.find_all('img'):
         try:
             if img['src'].startswith('http') and img['src'].endswith('jpg'):  
                 imgs_urls.append(img['src'])
        except:  
             pass
     print(str(cnt + j))
     cnt += 2

 driver.close()

 return(imgs_urls)

def download_image(url,filename):
  full_name = str(filename)  + ".jpg"
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'C:/Python/' + full_name)
  print(full_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":

  count2 = 0
  searchText = 'sites:pinterest white dress'
  filename = 'white dress'

  for url2 in Remainder_All_ImagesURLs_Google(searchText):
      download_image(url2, filename + str(count2))
      count2 += 1
      print(url2)
```

## imgs_url array:

```
297
['https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/3f/1b/1d/3f1b1decd26c10e3ce0a14d270c4a3db.jpg' #####syncopation##### 'http://24myfashion.com/2016/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Red-and-white-dress-2017-2018-15.jpg', 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/84/3d/c5/843dc5b9879801fce8ca33b569948143.jpg']
```

## Output:

```
white dress0.jpg
https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/3f/1b/1d/3f1b1decd26c10e3ce0a14d270c4a3db.jpg

#####syncopation#####

white dress101.jpg
https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/4e/9e/83/4e9e83b4aaf3224b5b26482b4639004f.jpg**
```

## Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ajh46/PycharmProjects/untitled3/Crawling.py", line 216, in <module>
download_image(url2, filename + str(count2))
  File "C:/Users/ajh46/PycharmProjects/untitled3/Crawling.py", line 192, in download_image
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'C:/Python/' + full_name)
  File "C:\Users\ajh46\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\ajh46\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ajh46\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\ajh46\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\ajh46\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ajh46\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ajh46\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: I just don't like scraping Google, it's not smart they invented Captcha.
That's the first bit of advice.
Second, Google tracks everything from clicks to how you behave and that's probably why your Selenium got blocked.
That's a status code Forbidden meaning No, no !

Comment: I can not understand your advice. Is there no way to fix that error?

Answer (score 0):

`.urlretrieve()` has no cookies or session like in selenium browser that why you got 403, and you also need to set user-agent.
Just change your `download_image()` function to the following

```py
def download_image(url,filename):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(url)
    userAgent = browser.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
    seleniumCookies= browser.get_cookies()
    cookies = ''
    for cookie in seleniumCookies:
        cookies += '%s=%s;' % (cookie['name'], cookie['value'])

    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', userAgent)]
    opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', cookies))
    full_name = str(filename)  + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'C:/Python/' + full_name)
    print(full_name)
```

Hope this helps :)